# Implementing my own Map API in java, how do I throw IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, api, class, dictionary

I'm implementing a custom class in java that implements Map .  According to the map api I need to throw an IllegalArgumentException for the put(k,v) and putAll(map) methods.

I believe I throw this exception if I have something like:

```
MyMapClass<Integer, Integer> map = new MyMapClass<Integer, Integer>;
```

and then I call

```
map.put ("hello",5).
```

Am I correct that this is the situation that should cause the exception?

If so, can I get some direction as to how I can test for this?  I'm not sure how to find out what type of objects k and v are in the put method.

Comment: My java is rusty so I might be way off base... but if map is a map of Integer's to Integer's, will your example even compile?

Comment: No, it won't compile.  The OP is confusing the compile time exception that would be thrown by the above example with a run time exception that is mentioned by the map API.  As @Affe has pointed out, the run time exception mentioned by the API should only be thrown if the new Map implementation has a special requirement that is not met (eg if the new Map requires a positive key and a negative key is specified).

Answer (score 3):

That would be a compile time error for trying to use a String where the compiler is expecting an Integer.  There isn't a general case where you *need* to throw IllegalArgumentException, it's just an option that the Interface allows for your map to do if you have some special rules that aren't otherwise enforced.

If you have no special restrictions to apply to the content, there is no reason to throw the exception.  You will notice that `java.util.HashMap` does not actually throw it!

Example, if you had a class where only positive Integers are accepted as keys:

```
public class MyMapKeyedOnPositiveInts<V> implements Map<Integer, V> {

    public V put (Integer key, V value) {
        if (key < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        //do put
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Java API for [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface Java 5 (to current) you through an IllegalArgumentException;

> if some aspect of this key or value prevents it from being stored in this map

The example you provided is not what the Map API requires, this is because of Generics. In Java 5+ Java will ensure that it will be a compile time error what you have specified above and thus you can rest assured you don't need to check for the correct type in the `put` and `putAll` methods.

So what does the above statement from the `Map` JavaDoc then mean for you? Well it really depends on what it is that you are doing in your implementation of the `Map` interface. A lot of the implementations of `Map` in the Java do not throw the exception (`HashMap`, `TreeMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, etc).